# How to see MS Project version programmatically

Tags: development, project-server, project-online

I have two environments of MS Project. One is Project Server 2013, and the other is Project Online. With just the PWA Url, can I know which type of environment I'm trying to connect?

If just the URL is not enough, what's the minimum of information needed to know this programmatically?

I need to know this because apparently, I'll need to use [NetworkCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to login to Project Server, but if I'm connecting to Project Online, then I'll need to use [SharePointOnlineCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Online is always going to have a host name like `tenant.sharepoint.com`. Your on-prem instance is going to have it's on specific url. This should be sufficient enough for you to determine which credential method to use.

Comment: Now that's being clever! Nice one mate :)